# How to get highest value of the array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, csv

So I want to create a PHP application which will find highest value of "Amount" in my CSV file.

My csv file looks like this:

```
Day     Amount
1       10
2       17
3       22
4       48
5       12
...
```

First of all, I did this, I parsed my .csv file into an array:

```
$fh = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r+');
$lines = array();
while( ($row = fgetcsv($fh, 8192)) !== FALSE ) {
    $lines[] = $row;
}
```

What should I do now if I want to loop throught the "Amount" values, and I want to save the highest value into variable `$x`?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Sort the array in ascending order, select the first element?

Comment: `rsort($lines); echo $lines[0];`

Comment: `max($lines)` or, for multidimensional array: `max( array_column( $lines, 'Amount' ) )`

Comment: I don't know if you need later the array but if not you could check for the highest value directly in the `while` loop - it may have a bit better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in PHP max() for one dimension arrays or loop through and check yourself http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

```
$x = max($lines);

$x = 0;
foreach($lines as $key=>$line){
    if($line[1]) >$x){
       $x = $line[1];
    }

}
```

Comment: `$lines` is a multi-dimensional array, so this won't work.

Comment: It was always multi-dimensional, because `fgetcsv()` always returns an array. The edit simply clarified how many columns it has.

Answer (score 0):

Make another array containing the amounts, and get the max value of that.

```
$fh = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r+');
$lines = array();
$amounts = array();
while( ($row = fgetcsv($fh, 8192)) !== FALSE ) {
    $lines[] = $row;
    if (count($row) > 1 && is_numeric($row[1])) { // skip header
        $amounts = $row[1];
    }
}
$max_amount = max($amounts);
```

You could also calculate the max while reading the lines.

```
$fh = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r+');
$lines = array();
$max_amount = 0;
while( ($row = fgetcsv($fh, 8192)) !== FALSE ) {
    $lines[] = $row;
    if (count($row) > 1 && is_numeric($row[1]) && $row[1] > $max_amount) { // skip header
        $max_amount = $row[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer. I have a problem:
.csv file actually looks like this (first 7 lines are empty and the numbers 0, 1, 2... are here just to help you understand): http://i.imgur.com/M7TJvUP.png When I run your code, I get an error that offset is undefined. Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: Check the length of `$row` before trying to use `$row[1]`.

Comment: When the line is empty, `$row` will be an empty array. Why do you have empty lines in a CSV file anyway?

Comment: I've updated the answer, although I think it should have been obvious.

Comment: It works now, although there is a bug. First of all, thank you for all the help! You wouldn't believe how much it means to me. And about bug... Let's say I have 2 values stored in my array: 999 and 1031. Value 1031 is stored in this format 1.031 (I export the data from the website so I can't change the format) So the bug is that the program stores 999 as the highest value, even though 1031 is greater. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: PHP can't parse numbers with commas in them. Remove the commas before trying to use it as a number. What's so hard about that? I think you need to hire a real programmer, because you're going to drive yourself crazy if you have to post to SO for every little detail like this.

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP's max to get the max value from array !

```
max ( array $values )
```

You can read more about PHP max function at :
[PHP max function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)

Comment: Doesn't work by itself with a multi-dimensional array.